# Large XML file Parsing Chunk data Filetering in PHP

Tags: php, xml, regex, xml-parsing

I have a large XML file more than 100 MB. I am reading the file in chunks like this

> $fp = fopen('large.xml', 'r');
>
> while ($data = fread($fp, 4096)) {

The format of XML is like this

```
<PersonalInfo>
    <UserDetail>
       <FirstName>ABC</FirstName>
       <Occupation>Student</Occupation>
       <DateOfBirth>08/14/1999</DateOfBirth>
    </UserDetail>
    <CaseDetail>....</CaseDetail>
    <TransactionDetail>....</TransactionDetail>
</PersonalInfo>      
<PersonalInfo>
    <UserDetail>
       <FirstName>XYZ</FirstName>
       <Occupation>Student</Occupation>
       <DateOfBirth>04/25/1991</DateOfBirth>
     </UserDetail>
     <CaseDetail>....</CaseDetail>
     <TransactionDetail>.....</TransactionDetail>
</PersonalInfo>      
<PersonalInfo>
    <UserDetail>
        <FirstName>DEF</FirstName>
        <Occupation>Teacher</Occupation>
        <DateOfBirth>05/12/1984</DateOfBirth>
    </UserDetail>
    <CaseDetail>....</CaseDetail>
    <TransactionDetail>...</TransactionDetail>
</PersonalInfo>
```

I want to just include those records where the Occupation TAG is "Student"  and write those results to a CSV file.

I have tried the preg_match as
preg_match( "/\(.*?)\</PersonalInfo>/s", $data, $match );
to select the Tags and then look into $match but it is returning double values(repetition).

Comment: Try using the PHP XML parser: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php
Great for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if your xml is valid with the help of following link :

http://www.xmlformatter.net/

If your xml is valid then do following :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$dom->formatOutput = true;
@$dom->load('large.xml');
$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('PersonalInfo');

foreach ($tags as $destination) {

    foreach($destination->childNodes as $child) {
        if ($child->textContent == "Student") {
          echo "Write code to create csv file";
        }
    }
}
```